# Why Qt application on Windows gets detached in PowerShell and Command Prompt but not in GitBash?

Tags: c++, qt, git-bash, cout, mingw32

I have a Windows Qt application built using QMake / x86_64-w64-mingw32 on Linux.

As the interesting things happen before the `QApplication` is created, my `main.cpp` shall be enough to demonstrate:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QTextStream>

#include "mainwindow.h"

static QScopedPointer<QFile> logFile;

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context,
                    const QString &msg) {
  QTextStream out(logFile.data());
  out << qFormatLogMessage(type, context, msg) << endl;
  out.flush();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  qInfo() << APP_PRODUCT << " ver. " << APP_GIT_VERSION;

  const QFileInfo app(argv[0]);
  const QString logFileName(app.baseName() + ".log");
  const QString logFilePath(app.dir().absoluteFilePath(logFileName));
  logFile.reset(new QFile(logFilePath));

  if (logFile.data()->open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text)) {
    qInfo() << "Log file " << logFilePath;
  } else {
    qFatal("Unable to create log file %s", logFilePath.toLocal8Bit().data());
  }

  qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);

  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

For debugging in release I wanted to use some `qInfo` and `qFatal` (tried `std::cout`), but when I try to run the app from PowerShell or Windows Command prompt the application gets detached (next `C:\Program Files\MyApp>` appears before my app finishes) and no cli output is visible.

When I start the same app using GitBash it does not get detached and all the `cout`s are displayed as in standard terminal app.

My two questions:

1. why it works differently in GitBash and PowerShell -is this related to cross-compilation?
2. how can I display `qDebug`, `qInfo` etc (or `cout`, `cerr`) in standard Windows terminals?

Comment: This depends on how you link your application -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem
You can set this with cmake (see add_executable) or qmake (CONFIG += console)

Comment: Thanks, @chehrlic, this seems to explain the "why ... ?" question. [EDIT: It actually does not explain the difference between CMD and GitBash, just why it doesn't work in the former one.] Unfortunately I can't add `console` to my config, as with `QT += core gui multimedia sql console` qmake says: ":-1: error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: console". I understand one can't have both `gui` and `console` in one app. -Is that right?

Comment: Please re-read my first comment. I never said anything about 'QT += console' ...

Comment: I have added `console` in a wrong place... `CONFIG += console` works. Automatically opens terminal window when running the EXE. Thanks for pointing this out!